# List comprehension to create list of strings from two lists

Tags: python, list, functional-programming

I have two lists of strings and I want to use them to create a list of strings.

```
m1 = ["Ag", "Pt"]
m2 = ["Ir", "Mn"]
codes = []
for i in range (len (m1) ):
    codes.append('6%s@32%s' %(m1[i], m2[i] ) )
print codes
```

For example codes could have the elements ["6Ag@32Ir", "6Pt@32Mn"]

I want to turn the following into a list comprehension.

Comment: you need to have `codes = []` before the `for` loop.

Comment: edited question.  I want to make the for loop into a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-zip method:

```
>>> m1 = ["Ag", "Pt"]
>>> m2 = ["Ir", "Mn"]
>>> ['6%s@32%s' %(m1[i], m2[i]) for i in range(min(len(m1), len(m2)))]
['6Ag@32Ir', '6Pt@32Mn']
```

Turn that into a generator:

```
>>> ('6%s@32%s' %(m1[i], m2[i]) for i in xrange(min(len(m1), len(m2))))
```

Python 2, you can do:

```
>>> ['6%s@32%s' % (x, y) for x, y in map(None, m1, m2)]
['6Ag@32Ir', '6Pt@32Mn']
```

Or, you do not even need to unpack the tuple:

```
>>> ['6%s@32%s' % t for t in map(None, m1, m2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `zip` them and print them like this

```
m1, m2 = ["Ag", "Pt"], ["Ir", "Mn"]
print ["6{}@32{}".format(*items) for items in zip(m1, m2)]
# ['6Ag@32Ir', '6Pt@32Mn']
```

Or, if you prefer `map` approach,

```
from itertools import starmap
print list(starmap("6{}@32{}".format, zip(m1, m2)))
```

Or

```
print [item for item in starmap("6{}@32{}".format, zip(m1, m2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> m1 = ["Ag", "Pt"]
>>> m2 = ["Ir", "Mn"]
>>> zip(m1, m2)  #  zip is used to pair-up the items in m1 and m2
[('Ag', 'Ir'), ('Pt', 'Mn')]
>>> ["6%s@32%s" % x for x in zip(m1, m2)]
['6Ag@32Ir', '6Pt@32Mn']
>>>
```

Note that if `m1` and `m2` can be large, you should use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of `zip` (which, in Python 2.x, creates an unnecessary list).  However, the lists in your example are small enough that this is not a problem.